# index should be in range...but isn't

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, grammar

I'm trying to write code that will check whether someone has switched tenses within the same sentence. It takes data from a text box, splits it into sentences, splits those sentences into words and checks the words against a list of verbs in different tenses. If the sentence is inconsistent, it highlights it. I have successfully done this much however I also want to keep the format of the text the same in the text box when I return it. The program does this as well, however if the first sentence of one paragraph is inconsistent, it will highlight all the space between the first paragraph as well as the sentence. I tried running an `if` statement that looks for extended whitespace and separates it from the sentence, so the highlighter doesn't include it as part of the sentence. I keep getting this error however: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is relevant code:

```
def verbTense(self):#Checks sentences for inconsistent tenses
    text=self.input.get(1.0,'end')
    self.input.delete(1.0,'end')
    text=sentenceSplit(text)
    self.input.tag_config('verb',background='yellow')
    for i in text:
        if inconsistentTense(i)==True:
            self.input.insert('end',i,'verb')
        else:
            self.input.insert('end',i)

def sentenceSplit(x):#Splits a string into sentences.
    fullText=[]
    tempSentence=[]
    x=formatSplit(x)
    index=0
    for i in x:
        if i==" " and x[index+1]==" ":
            fullText.append(i)
        else:
            if ".)" in i or "!" in i or "?" in i or "." in i or "!)" in i or "?)" in i or ")" in i or "]" in i or "}" in i:
                tempSentence.append(i)
                sentence=listIntoWord(tempSentence)
                fullText.append(sentence)
                tempSentence=[]
            else:
                tempSentence.append(i)
        index+=1
    return fullText

def listIntoWord(x):#Combines list of strings into one single string.
    text=""
    for i in x:
        text+=str(i)
    return text

def formatSplit(x):#Splits a string into different words while keeping the spaces. 
    wordString=[]
    totalString=[]
    for i in x:
        if i==" ":
            wordString=listIntoWord(wordString)
            totalString.append(wordString)
            wordString=[]
            totalString.append(i)
        else:
            wordString.append(i) 
    return totalString
```

Comment: wall of text ... tldr ;;; your index is out of range.... please post a small self contained example demonstrating your problem ...

Comment: full stack trace please, which line has the error ?

Comment: if i==" " and x[index+1]==" ": <== this line.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sentenceSplit(x):#Splits a string into sentences.
    fullText=[]
    tempSentence=[]
    x=formatSplit(x)
    index=0
    for i in x:
        if i==" " and x[index+1]==" ":  # THIS LINE COULD BE PROBLEMATIC AT LAST ITERATION
            fullText.append(i)
```

As at the end of the loop `index` will point to the last character in your string, and accesing `x[index+1]` would raise an IndexError.

Comment: I thought that too, only I added temporary periods at the end and it still highlighted the space in between.

Comment: wait it would still test it, so would i have to add an if statement making sure i'm not at the end of the iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with these lines of code in `sentenceSplit()`:

```
index=0
for i in x:
    if i==" " and x[index+1]==" ":
        ...
    ...
    index+=1
```

The body of this loop will be executed `len(x)` times, on the very last iteration `index` will be `len(x)-1`, so `x[index+1]` will be equivalent to `x[len(x)]`.  This will cause an IndexError because the last item in a sequence `x` is at index `len(x)-1`, so `len(x)` is past the end of the sequence.

To fix this you can do one of two things:

- Only loop up to the second to last item so when you look ahead on each iteration you never pass the end of the sequence:

  ```
  for index, i in enumerate(x[:-1]):
      if i == " " and x[index+1] == " ":
          ...
  ```
- Don't perform the check of the next item on the last iteration:

  ```
  for index, i in enumerate(x):
      if i == " " and (index == len(x)-1 or x[index+1] == " "):
          ...
  ```

You can choose whichever is more appropriate for you code.

Note that I also modified the code so that it uses `enumerate()`, which is the preferred way to loop over both items and indices.